# Swift 2.2 Xcode 7.3 touch not working in specific area marked below

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2, xcode7

I am new to ios. Throughout my application touch is not working in specific area. when i move that part up by scrooling touch works on that button/textfield properly.
I have checked my phone it is working fine if i close the application

Area in which touch is not working:

[image]

Comment: probably you have some view with transparent background which blocks your touches on their way to scroll view?

Comment: No i am not having any view there.

Comment: Thanks i didn't notice it was my progressview which was not closing properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: load your app on view where this problem is and tap on Debug view hierarchy button

[image]

Spin view around there to see if there something blocking touches

Comment: Thanks i didn't notice it was my progressview which was not closing properly